# flowplayer video quality depending on bandwith

Tags: video, flowplayer, bitrate

In flowplayer is there any way to check the user bandwidth and serve video accordingly. The flowplayer docs says to store separate video files for each bitrate (800,1200 and 1600). Is there any way to reduce the quality of video show without storing separate files in order to achieve low buffer time.

Using ffmpeg we can change the bitrate of video files and save video files of different sizes. But I am asking whether we can do any anything in the client video player end ? In this way I need to store only one hd video in my server.

http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/bwcheck.html

In the above page I am saying about the following portion of code :

```
  bitrates: [
         {
            url: "mp4:bbb-800", width: 480, bitrate: 800,
            // this is the default bitrate, the playback kicks off with this and after that
            // Quality Of Service monitoring adjusts to the most appropriate bitrate
            isDefault: true
         },
         { url: "mp4:bbb-1200", width: 720, bitrate: 1200 },
         { url: "mp4:bbb-1600", width: 1080, bitrate: 1600 }
       ]
```